# Oracle 11g XE: How to transform a LEFT SQL JOIN to a query that uses semijoins and correlated queries?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to transform an SQL statement that uses LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.FIRST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES t1
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES t2 ON t1.EMPLOYEE_ID = t2.MANAGER_ID
WHERE t2.MANAGER_ID IS NULL
```

to an SQL query that uses semijoins and corelated queries. How to do that?

Comment: What result would you get? What should represent each column obtained?

Comment: The result is a table of employees first names that are not present in the list of manager's first names.

Comment: The query looks correct. Why do you want to write it differently?

Comment: It's a quiz that states that: "Select all the EMPLOYEES which FIRST_NAME is not present in the list of manager's FIRST_NAME's using semijoins and corelated queries" thats why I want to know how to do that because I know how to do it with an SQL LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Your query is not a correct answer to the question, even using `LEFT JOIN`, assuming that the manager id can be null in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.FIRST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM EMPLOYEES t2
    WHERE t1.EMPLOYEE_ID = t2.MANAGER_ID
)
```

Comment: According to the documentation this is a anti-join: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52355 is it possible to do the same with an semi-join that uses only EXISTS or IN? I can't think of a solution without a NOT operator. Thanks.

Comment: This query is not quite equivalent to the OP's query.  There are two way for the manager id to be `NULL`, although this is correct for the question.